# Laravel load multiple view in a single function

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

i just know how to call multiple views in a single controller function.

i am trying this:

```
return  View::make('header');
return  View::make('main');
return  View::make('footer');
```

Any suggestion.How can i call them??
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a view with [sections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates) for ease of re-use. It then allows you to compose the various sections.

**layout.blade.php**

```
@yield('header')
@yield('body')
@yield('footer')
```

**combined.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('header')
    @include('header')
@stop

@section('body')
    @include('body')
@stop

@section('footer')
    @include('footer')
@stop
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

function index()
{
    return view('combined');
}
```

**Directory structure**

```
/resources
  /views
    /combined.blade.php
    /layouts
      /layout.blade.php
```

Comment: can you please explain how to do it??

Comment: its not working..error with View [combined] not found.

Comment: are all the view files in the /views folder at the root level?

Comment: in resources/views/layouts folder

Comment: the layout can be placed in the layouts folder, the rest should be at the resources/views level, I will add the directory structure in the example, make sure you update the @extends tag in your combined view

Answer (score 2):

`return` keyword stops execution of your method/function so it'll just ignore the rest of lines.

You can try concatenate that `make` calls if it's what you need.

```
return  View::make('header') . View::make('main') . View::make('footer');
```

But maybe it's not what you want to do? Why not using templating systems and include this files in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single line method to load more than one blade.

for example:

```
return view('header').view('login').view('footer');
```

Comment: Note that there is already an accepted answer to this question. Please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.